# CentOS - Forwarding all ports except one

Tags: centos, firewall, port-forwarding, firewalld

It is possible to forward all ports (TCP/UDP) in a CentOS server except by the ssh/sftp port (TCP port 22).

If it is possible how can I do this?

I thought in something using "FirewallD".

Thank you! =D

Comment: Where do you want to "forward" your ports?

Comment: All for the same "ip" which in turn will redirect everything to other machines. Let's assume that the ip is `192.168.56.123`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build a NAT solution, you may use IPtables for this purpose.

Here is a good article for you:
[RedHat iptables](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html)

You may also do something fancy and use [LVS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Virtual_Server_Administration/ch-lvs-setup-VSA.html). This will essentially enable you to forward packets to multiple destination and work as a load-balancer.

Comment: Could you exemplify?